# Laravel 5.1 - Give me the very recent row - lastOrFail

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

According to the [official](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) documentation:

> The findOrFail and firstOrFail methods will retrieve the first result
>   of the query.

Cool. I would like something opposite.

Let's assume that I have a table with bunch of columns where multiple rows can have the same `type_id` and can belong to the same `person_id`.

I can obviously create **queryScope** or **raw query** but maybe you know something like `lastOrFail`?

Simply it would to return the most recent row from all that fulfil a particular condition. Something like:

```
$model = $this->makeModel()
            ->where('person_id', '=', $personId)
            ->where('type_id', '=', $typeId)
            ->lastOrFail();
```

Did you know something like that or do you see a need that this should be implemented in Laravel natively by Taylor?

Comment: There's no such thing as `lastOrFail()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you order the items in reverse, `firstOrFail` will give you the last item:

```php
$query = Model::where('person_id', $personId)->where('type_id', $typeId);

$model = $query->latest()->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: That's a perfect solution. Thanks!